# Can't request ride with specific product id [Uber Rides-API Java v. 0.5.1]

Tags: uber-api

I'm doing migration to the newest version of yours java sdk rides-api - 0.5.1

I've one problem with requesting uber (in sandbox mode) - when I try to request uber and parallelly accept that then I'm getting back with info saying that uber with such productId couldn't be found. 
This is weird because these are exactly what I get when asking for taxi-proposals (combination of price-estimates and get-product endpoints).
Any idea whats going on?

I'm getting the following error message (while trying to accept the ride in sandbox mode):

code: not_found,
status: 404,
title: Invalid product "929fcc19-8cb4-4007-a54f-3ab34473700f"

Comment: What do you mean by "request uber and parallelly accept"? You have to wait for a ``request_id`` to change the status in sandbox mode.

Comment: Let me be more clear. When I do first request for uber with specific `product_id` then (when still waiting for response) I do another request to sandbox endpoint with this `product_id` and status `accept`. When doing that I'm getting the above error msg with 404 status (the id that I'm passing is not corrupted).

Comment: How did you get the product id ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly. Here's what I understand:

1. You make a `POST /v1/requests/` requesting a ride with a specific `product_id`
2. Before you receive a response for the POST, you send a `PUT /v1/sandbox/requests/{request_id}` with status `accept`

Is this correct? In other words, you want to create a request and accept it right away?

If so, you should probably double check your second `PUT`. It requires a **request_id** and not a **product_id**.

Otherwise, if you actually are making a `PUT /v1/sandbox/products/{product_id}` with the product_id, your intent would be to modify the available products and would have nothing to do with the status.

Comment: The other problem I've is requesting ride with specific `product_id` (`POST /v1/requests`). As a response I immediately end up having the same error msg with 404 status (means product not found).

Comment: Where do you get the product_id from? They are different from location to location. You should always do a get on products before using the id for other calls. Can you be more specific, maybe even clearly post your requests and responses please?

Comment: I get the `product_id` from `GET /v1/estimates/price`. The flow of uber requesting is following: 1) `GET /v1/estimates/price`. I grab `product_id` from response and then do 2) `POST /v1/requests/` using the same {start_latitude, start_latitude, end_latitude, end_longitude} when asking for price estimates. After that as a response I get an info "Invalid product id, code not_found, status 404" which is weird.

Comment: Being more specific. I ask `GET /v1/estimates/price` with such input: `start_latitude=40.7141667 start_longitude=-74.0063889 end_latitude=40.8241667 end_longitude=-74.1063889`. I get list of 8 different proposals with such ids: `id: 929fcc19-8cb4-4007-a54f-3ab34473700f
id: b8e5c464-5de2-4539-a35a-986d6e58f186
id: 1e0ce2df-4a1e-4333-86dd-dc0c67aaabe1
id: d6d6d7ad-67f9-43ef-a8de-86bd6224613a
id: 0e9d8dd3-ffec-4c2b-9714-537e6174bb88
id: 56487469-0d3d-4f19-b662-234b7576a562
id: 1864554f-7796-4043-82d4-883ddde1070a
id: ebe413ab-cf49-465f-8564-a71119bfa449`. I choose the second one and...

Comment: which is `b8e5c464-5de2-4539-a35a-986d6e58f186`. Using the same start and end location with the following id I do request `POST /v1/requests/`. As a result I get client error `code: not_found,
status: 404,
title: Invalid product "b8e5c464-5de2-4539-a35a-986d6e58f186". Available:`. PS: I test that whole flow against `https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1` url

Comment: any idea whats going on?

Comment: sorry for the late response - I'd suggest we continue our conversation on GitHub. Mind submitting an issue [here](https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk/issues/new)? Thanks!